# Colors Messed Up For Cube Rendered Using Tessellator and BufferBuilder

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm working on a Forge 1.12.2 Mod. One of the features I need is Schematica-like ghost block rendering. I'm trying to draw cubes using Tesselator and BufferBuilder but the colors don't render properly. Here is my code

```
        Tessellator tessy = Tessellator.getInstance();
        BufferBuilder buf = tessy.getBuffer();

        GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
        GlStateManager.disableCull();
        GlStateManager.disableLighting();

        GlStateManager.alphaFunc(GL11.GL_ALWAYS, 0);
        GlStateManager.translate(-x, -y, -z);

        buf.begin(GL11.GL_QUADS, DefaultVertexFormats.POSITION_COLOR);
        
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        z = 100;

        // south side [pos z] [parent x]
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        // north side [neg z] [parent x]
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        // east side [pos x] [parent z]
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        // west side [neg x] [parent z]
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        // top [pos y] [parent x & y]
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        // bottom [neg y] [parent x & y]
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x + 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z + 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();
        buf.pos(x - 0.5f, y - 0.5f, z - 0.5f).color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).endVertex();

        tessy.draw();

        GlStateManager.enableLighting();
        GlStateManager.enableCull();
        GlStateManager.disableAlpha();
        GlStateManager.popMatrix();
```

and it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1cYA.jpg.
One thing that I noticed is that the black color that I want it to render as renders when I'm looking in the +x, +z direction, and looking slightly down.

If anyone has any idea why this is happening, help would be appreciated.